# no post using ion library

Tags: android, post, android-ion

I am trying to post a json object through android ion library on a computer in my local network with the following code :

```
String url = "http://192.168.1.23/ws/svn/branches/application/public/connectMobile";
                    try {


                        JsonObject json = new JsonObject();
                        json.addProperty("email", email.getText().toString());
                        json.addProperty("psw", password.getText().toString());
                        Log.i("json envoyé",json.toString());



                            Ion.with(context)
                                    .load("POST",url)
                                    .addHeader("Content-Type", "application/json")
                                    .setLogging("ion-geny", Log.DEBUG)
                                    .setJsonObjectBody(json)
                                    .asJsonObject()
                                    .setCallback(new FutureCallback<JsonObject>() {
                                        @Override
                                        public void onCompleted(Exception e, JsonObject result) {
                                            if (result != null)
                                            {
                                                Log.i("result",result.toString());
                                            }
                                            else
                                            {
                                                Log.i("result","null");
                                            }
                                            if (e != null)
                                            {
                                                Log.i("error",e.toString());

                                            }
                                            else
                                            {
                                                Log.i("error","null");
                                            }

                                        }

                                    });



                    } catch (Exception ex) {
                        ex.printStackTrace();
                        Log.i("except", ex.toString());
                    }
```

The debug gives this :

> 09-27 12:19:43.302    3309-3309/com.bewizme.bewizmeloginsample
>   I/email﹕ f@f.com
>       09-27 12:19:43.302    3309-3309/com.bewizme.bewizmeloginsample I/Password﹕ f
>       09-27 12:19:43.362    3309-3309/com.bewizme.bewizmeloginsample I/connected﹕ connected true
>       09-27 12:19:43.402    3309-3309/com.bewizme.bewizmeloginsample D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 142K, 7% free 2917K/3116K, paused 15ms,
>   total 18ms
>       09-27 12:19:43.482    3309-3309/com.bewizme.bewizmeloginsample I/json envoyé﹕ {"email":"f@f.com","psw":"f"}
>       09-27 12:19:43.602    3309-3309/com.bewizme.bewizmeloginsample D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 154K, 6% free 3275K/3480K, paused 14ms,
>   total 15ms
>       09-27 12:19:43.622    3309-3309/com.bewizme.bewizmeloginsample D/ion-geny﹕ (0 ms)
>   http://192.168.1.23/ws/svn/branches/application/public/connectMobile:
>   preparing request
>       09-27 12:19:43.632    3309-3309/com.bewizme.bewizmeloginsample I/ion-geny﹕ (0 ms)
>   http://192.168.1.23/ws/svn/branches/application/public/connectMobile:
>   Using loader: com.koushikdutta.ion.loader.HttpLoader@b20a3808
>       09-27 12:19:43.652    3309-3331/com.bewizme.bewizmeloginsample D/ion-geny﹕ (0 ms)
>   http://192.168.1.23/ws/svn/branches/application/public/connectMobile:
>   Executing request.
>       09-27 12:19:44.862    3309-3331/com.bewizme.bewizmeloginsample D/ion-geny﹕ (1212 ms)
>   http://192.168.1.23/ws/svn/branches/application/public/connectMobile:
>   Response is not cacheable
>       09-27 12:19:44.902    3309-3331/com.bewizme.bewizmeloginsample D/ion-geny﹕ (1249 ms)
>   http://192.168.1.23/ws/svn/branches/application/public/connectMobile:
>   Connection successful
>       09-27 12:19:45.002    3309-3331/com.bewizme.bewizmeloginsample D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 263K, 9% free 3462K/3788K, paused 61ms,
>   total 61ms
>       09-27 12:19:45.052    3309-3309/com.bewizme.bewizmeloginsample I/result﹕ null
>       09-27 12:19:45.052    3309-3309/com.bewizme.bewizmeloginsample I/error﹕ com.google.gson.JsonParseException: unable to parse json

I suspect that the parse error is due to the fact that nothing is returned.

Moreover, on my server, I wrote a piece of code to check what's coming in, and I receive nothing on the server from my sample but when trying with RESTEASY with firefox sending the same, the post is correctly sent my server receives the post and a response is sent back.

Any idea ? I can't figure out what's wrong...

Comment: Can you debug your application, check response, and check [here](http://jsonlint.com/) that if the JSON is valid or not?

Comment: json sent is correct : {"email":"f@f.com","psw":"f"}
Nothing is catch on the server side (like the post never arrives) and then response is null, which I suspect is good because the server never received, so never answered)

Comment: I think Gson handles nulls and empty strings well. So I also think the formatting problem is from the server's side... But I can't identify what.

Comment: There might be problem with JsonArray, Check is your server response is JsonObject or JsonArray?

Answer (score 0):

if you are getting stuck regarding json parsing error because when you get result into JsonObject formate and try to get string usually people write wrong parsing so I write it in String formate now you need not to parse it you can get your response in String so you can get String easily using .toString and there are lot of mechanism to do this problem and lot of way to write code but meaning would be same but sometime you write code same and meaning also same but compiler could not translate it. so we get error that's why I write here string now you can get your response.

```
  .addHeader("Content-Type", "application/json")
                                .setLogging("ion-geny", Log.DEBUG)
                                .setJsonObjectBody(jsobj.getAsJsonObject())
                            .asString()
                                .setCallback(new FutureCallback<String>() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onCompleted(Exception e, String result) {
                                        if (result != null)
                                        {
                                            Log.i("result",result.toString());
```

Comment: It would be great if you'd not only just drop some code, but also give an explanation of what is going on in his and your code. It helps the question author and other users. It's good if it works, but knowing why is even more important in my opinion.

Comment: if you are getting stuck regarding json parsing error because when you get result into JsonObject formate and try to get string usually people write wrong parsing so I write it in String formate now you need not to parse it you can get your response in String so you can get String easily using .toString and there are lot of mechanism to do this problem and lot of way to write code but meaning would be same but sometime you write code same and meaning also same but compiler could not translate it. so we get error that's why I write here string now you can get your response.